# CoreText crashed when run in multiple threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading, core-text

Crashed when I calculate layout in multiple threads . I've looked up the answers but there are mostly out of date . They said that there is Apple's CoreText bug , and has been fixed . But crashed models include iPhone6、iPhone6s、iPhone7、iPhone8，operate system from ios 10 to 11.1 . 
So, anyone can help, thx

```
Thread 42 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181313568 __CFBasicHashDrain :216 
    (in CoreFoundation)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181289b44 _CFRelease :224 (in 
CoreFoundation)
2   CoreText                        0x0000000184a7dbf4 
    TDescriptor::~TDescriptor() :132 (in CoreText)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181289b44 _CFRelease :224 (in 
    CoreFoundation)
4   CoreText                        0x0000000184a9533c TFont::~TFont() :248 
    (in CoreText)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181289b44 _CFRelease :224 (in 
    CoreFoundation)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001813135c8 __CFBasicHashDrain :312 
    (in CoreFoundation)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181289b44 _CFRelease :224 (in 
    CoreFoundation)
8   CoreText                        0x0000000184a8cc9c 
    TFontCascade::~TFontCascade() :40 (in CoreText)
9   CoreText                        0x0000000184abd35c 
    TGlyphEncoder::EncodeChars(CFRange, TAttributes const&, 
    TGlyphEncoder::Fallbacks) :1420 (in CoreText)
10  CoreText                        0x0000000184a8a46c 
    TTypesetterAttrString::Initialize(__CFAttributedString const*) :240 (in 
    CoreText)
11  CoreText                        0x0000000184a8a250 
    TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*) 
    :112 (in CoreText)
12  CoreText                        0x0000000184ac7f10 
    _CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString :56 (in CoreText)
```